# Stokes theorem 2 sides not matching with Magnetic waves

Tags: differential-geometry, stokes-theorem, electromagnetism

We have been asked to verify stokes theorem for a magnetic field.

We know Stokes theorem states, for any vector field $\vec{H}$:
$$\int_S{(\nabla \times \vec{H}) \cdot \vec{dS}} = \oint_L{\vec{H} \cdot \vec{dL}}$$

The field is given in the cylindrical co-ordinate system by:

$$\vec{H} = (\frac{cos(\frac{ϕ}{2})}{2}, -\sin(\frac{ϕ}{2}), 0)$$

Naturally, $$\nabla \times \vec{H} = (0, 0, -\frac{3 \sin(\frac{ϕ}{2})}{4 \rho}) = \vec{J}$$

We were given the area $0<\rho<3 , 0<ϕ<2\pi, z = 2$

However, evaluating the 2 sides of stokes theorem over the surface and the perimeter, we get.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3{{\vec{J} \cdot (\rho d\rho dϕ\space \hat{az}})}=-9$$

and
$$\int_0^{2\pi}{\vec{H} \cdot (\rho dϕ\space \hat{aϕ})} = -12$$

$\hat{aϕ}$ and $\hat{az}$ are unit vectors along $ϕ$ and $z$ respectively.

I can't figure out why the 2 sides of stokes theorem are not matching up.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  Please use MathJax for all equations in your question, not just some of them;  it improves readability.  You can find a tutorial on how to use it [over on our sister mathematics site.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Also:  fundamentally this is a math question, not a physics question, so it may end up being migrated to [Math.SE].

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thank you! I just did. Should I also ask this in mathematics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: As you can see, it's been migrated over to Math.SE already!  I flagged it for possible migration and, apparently, other users agreed with me.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Sweet.

Comment: I'm confused. This field $\vec H$ is not even well-defined or continuous on the surface in question.

Comment: @TedShifrin I believe that it's both well defined and continuous on the surface is question. I feel like the notation might be confusing. The vector field H is only dependent on phi.

Comment: Yes, but note that the values at $\phi=0$ and $\phi=2\pi$ do not agree. Stokes's Theorem requires that the vector field be not only continuous but continuously differentiable throughout the region.

Comment: @TedShifrin WOW. My mind is literally blown. Could you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those not wanting to translate in and out of cylindrical coordinates, $\vec H$ corresponds to the $1$-form $\omega = \frac12\cos(\phi/2)dr - \sin(\phi/2)(r\,d\phi)$, and $d\omega = -\frac34\sin(\phi/2)dr\wedge d\phi$. If $D = \{r\le 3, z=2\}$, oriented upward, then
\begin{align*}\int_{\partial D}\omega &= -3\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\phi/2)d\phi = -3(4)=-12 \quad\text{and} \\ \int_D d\omega &= -\frac34\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3\sin(\pi/2)dr\,d\phi = -\frac34(12) = -9.
\end{align*} So what gives?

In a word, Stokes's Theorem cannot be applied here. The force field in question must be continuously differentiable throughout the surface. Your $\vec H$ is not even continuous (or well-defined): Note that $\vec H(r,0,z)\ne\vec H(r,2\pi,z)$.

Comment: kind of off topic but would you say stokes theorem should be valid for vector field (8z,0,-4x^3) anywhere?

Comment: Sure. Those are smooth (as differentiable as you want) functions!

Comment: Could you take a look at this @tedshifrin https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777894/stokes-theorem-not-holding