# Stokes theorem not holding

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem, electromagnetism

I have a vector field $\vec{H} = (8z,0,-4x^3)$

Naturally, $\nabla \times \vec{H} = (0,8+12x^2,0)$

Stokes theorem says:
$$
\int_s{\nabla \times \vec{H}} \cdot \vec{dS} = \oint_l{\vec{H} \cdot dl}
$$

When evaluating across the closed rectangular path defined by
$$P(2,3,4) \space, Q(4,3,4) \space, R(4,3,1) \space,S(2,3,1)$$

$$\int_s{\nabla \times \vec{H}} \cdot \vec{dS} = \int_1^4\int_2^4{8+12x^2 \space dx \space dz} = 720 \\$$

$$and$$

$$\oint_l{\vec{H} \cdot dl} = 
\int_P^Q{\vec{H} \cdot (dx \space \hat{ax})} \space + 
\int_Q^R{\vec{H} \cdot (-dz \space \hat{az})} \space + 
\int_R^S{\vec{H} \cdot (-dx \space \hat{ax})} \space + 
\int_S^P{\vec{H} \cdot (dz \space \hat{az})} \space$$

$$=
\int_2^4{8 *4 \space dx}\space+ 
\int_4^1{4*4^3 \space dz} \space + 
\int_4^2{-8*1 \space dx} \space + 
\int_1^4{-4*2^3 \space dz} \space$$

$$=
64 \space-\space 768 \space+\space 16 \space-96\space$$

$$=-784$$

I am almost certain about the signs of the path integrals but if I change the signs of two terms in the last expression to $$64+768-16-96$$
I get 720, which is supposed to  be the right answer.

Comment: Slow down. In what way do four points define a surface?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry. The surface inside the closed rectangular path defined by the points.

Comment: Please stop using differential geometry tags. Multivariable calculus suffices. OK, so this is a rectangle in the plane $y=3$. Your sign is wrong on the third term, because you negated twice.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry. differential-geometry was added by physics.stackexchange on my last question about stokes theorem. If the sign of the differential term is correct, H . (-dx ax) = -8z dx. and -8 * (2-4) = 16.

Comment: Oh, several signs are messed up. Be consistent. If $z$ is going from $4$ to $1$, you still integrate $dz$ (maybe you should review parametrizing line integrals). So on the second term the force is $-4(4^3)$, so your sign is wrong there too. Just be consistent and careful.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. Thank you. But wouldn't dl vectors sign be different from 1 to 4 and 4 to 1? Because that's what we were taught to do for the surfaces in divergence theorem.

Comment: Still chasing this out but note that in your double integral (first evaluation), $z$ goes from 1 to 4 not 3 and with this does result in 720.

Comment: In the expression with 4 line integrals, all the bounds of integration are correct (including where b<a), however in the second and third you would NOT negate the terms of $H$, so leave as is and get 720. Would you mind clarifying the meaning of the "hat" notation in the path integrals for me?

Comment: @AlgTop1854 The hat vector refers to the unit vector in the direction of integration. hat az is unit vector towards +ve z. This is from an EM class. We were taught divergence theorem right before this. In divergence theorem, we had to watch out for the normal of the surface. For example in cylindrical coordinates, vector dS of a closed cylinder would be (p dphi dp az) for top, (p dphi dz ap) for side and (p dphi dp (-az)) for bottom. I am just wondering why the direction matters with differential surface but not with differential length.

Comment: @rjpj1998 Thanks for that. I hadn't seen it that way before, often the integrand in the path integral is expressed as $\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$ where $\vec{r}$ refers to a parametrization in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  As to direction mattering, the line integral has to be consistent with the surface integral in terms of orientation, usually following a "left-hand rule" just we usually draw axes $x$, $y$ and $z$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: As an example easy to visualize, if the surface $S$ was a "magic carpet" sitting above the $xy$-plane, the normal vector implicit in the surface integral would point upwards, and the boundary would be traversed counter-clockwise for Stokes' theorem to work. In your example the boundary of the rectangle in $xz$-space (sitting at $y=3$) is traversed clockwise for this to work.  You'd get $-720$ if reversed. Hope this helps!

Comment: @AlgTop1854 It does help. That's the right hand rule that explains the relation betwen direction of current and magnetic field in our EM class. I'll be deleting this question in a few minutes.

Comment: No need to delete; you did not make a silly mistake and the discussion has good points for anyone looking for examples.